# Xamarin Android Bindings that uses Android.WorkManager

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

We are making an app that needs to use Android's WorkManager library. The dependency .AAR file is compiled and tested working. I was able to build a DLL by binding the dependency AAR file using Visual Studio's Java Bindings Project.

However, when the Xamarin Android project uses the dependency library that uses the Android WorkManager, it throws an exception:

```
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/WorkManager; ---> 
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.WorkManager" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.appname.app-vXQN7f21kz_QrhvSakWVRA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.appname.app-vXQN7f21kz_QrhvSakWVRA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.appname.app-vXQN7f21kz_QrhvSakWVRA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

I also tried downloading the Android WorkManager AAR file, created its own Bindings Library project, compiled that, and added it to the main Xamarin Forms project, along with the dependency AAR. But I get this error:

```
error: CommandsCompletedListener is not public in SystemAlarmDispatcher; cannot be accessed from outside package
    androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.SystemAlarmDispatcher.CommandsCompletedListener
```

Is there something I should include or modify in the dependency Bindings project?

I already tried adding the WorkManager AAR to the dependency Bindings project and using that, but I still get the `ClassNotFoundException`. Has anyone tried using a Java dependency that uses the WorkManager for Xamarin Android?

Comment: Hello, did you try adding the .jar file in the android project which contains the androidx.work.WorkManager class definition?

Comment: The xamarin team are working on androidx bindings. Before they officially release you might find this useful https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/tree/AndroidX

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin team just released a NuGet with Android WorkManager bindings:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime

Install this NuGet and make sure that your Xamarin.Android project is targeting Android SDK v28+. Then you should be able to use the AndroidX.Work namespace.